# how to call a callback function after user successfully follows me on instagram on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to enable a download button on my website after the user successfully follows me on Instagram. I have placed a Instagram follow button on my page.

Is there any way to track that user has successfully followed me ? I cannot find any call back function documented on the developers page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see on the Instragram API documentation there's [this section](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_follows) it actually works for your intentions.

It gets you this kind of JSON object with all your followers.

```
    {
    "data": [{
        "username": "kevin",
        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1325536697.jpg",
        "full_name": "Kevin Systrom",
        "id": "3"
    },
    {
        "username": "instagram",
        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_25025320_75sq_1340929272.jpg",
        "full_name": "Instagram",
        "id": "25025320"
    }]
}
```

Now, you only have to get a valid ACCES-TOKEN. Please reference:
[How to get an Instagram Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496511/how-to-get-an-instagram-access-token)

Comment: Thanks for the efforts but this is not what I want.