# instafeed.js no userId set

Tags: javascript, instafeedjs

I have over 10 customers are complaining the social feeds aren't loading on their live websites any more.

Since Instagram changed its API and policy on June 1st [instafeed](http://instafeedjs.com/) cannot fetch data from hashtags any more. There should still be access to your personal Instagram feed (after creating a developer.instagram account).

I have this as code, but I get the error userId not given (see below). But you can clearly see there is a userId set. Am I missing something?

```
    var feed = new Instafeed({
      get: 'user',
      userId: '2165473659',
      clientId: 'f07ffe90593f41079777e82d67fd3f18',
      limit: 9,

      // ....
```

Here you can find my full [JS function](https://gist.github.com/NicolasVanhecke/eb2d8e672e7fd1a742e770a866ec1340) where I use the instafeed.js

---

The error I get:

```
Uncaught Error: No user specified. Use the 'userId' option.        instafeed.js:223
```

Comment: Well thanks for the help @halfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to version [v1.4.0](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/releases/tag/v1.4.0), Instafeed.js required the `userId` option to be a number rather than a string.

You can either upgrade your copy of the library, or change the `userId` option in your example to be (note the absence of the `"` quotes):

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: "user",
    userId: 2165473659,
    clientId: "f07ffe90593f41079777e82d67fd3f18",
    limit: 9,
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, must have not seen it! Next error: `No access token. Use the 'accessToken' option.` Although the first point in the v1.4 update says accesToken is not needed anymore...

Comment: And adding one (following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496511/how-to-get-an-instagram-access-token) gives and `invalid accessToken`.