# How to get an Instagram Access Token for iOS

Tags: ios, callback, oauth-2.0, access-token, instagram-api

This is unfortunately, very poor documented, and I haven't been able to generate an `access_token` for iOS.

I followed [How to get an Instagram Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496511/how-to-get-an-instagram-access-token)

Got my id and secret, along with the redirect URI, and there are a couple of issues:

1. Can't get to register the URL scheme of the redirect URI, as Instagram explicitly asks for and `https://youcallback.com`, what is the scheme?
2. If I use the callback from OAuthSwift example, it does redirect, but I get this error and when I check, the URL fragment is `nil,` even though when I test it on the browser, I do get an `access_token`. I also tried an external, and internal WebView.

> serverError[No access_token, no code and no error provided by server]