# Instagram api returning 400(Bad Request) while accessing tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net, instagram-api

I am trying to get access token using Instagram API but in result i am getting 400(Bad request).
I am using https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token to get access token and also passing 5 parameters required to access this api. Code is in c#.
App status is Live on Instagram. Please help.

Here is my code

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary.Add("client_id", this.appId);
        dictionary.Add("client_secret", this.appSecret);
        dictionary.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        dictionary.Add("redirect_uri", returnUrl.AbsoluteUri);
        dictionary.Add("code", authorizationCode);
        string result;
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {

            string text = webClient.UploadString("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", MessagingUtilities.CreateQueryString(dictionary));
}
```

Comment: you can improve your question by mentioning some more details . e.g how are you authorizing users and are you using server side flow or implicit flow to get the auth token. You can go over the documentation to confirm the process you are following and update your question accordingly (link to IG docs- https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

Comment: Here is my code

Comment: i am following process properly. The app is already live and code was working fine few days ago. It has stopped suddenly.

Comment: it is very hard to guess why it has stopped if it was working before. One thing you can try is start over a new test sample code while following steps mentioned in docs and try to get that up and then compare it with your old code to see where it is failing. For starters I am not sure if Webclient will do encoding of data for you, you should check that , you can also check similar qs on so like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496511/how-to-get-an-instagram-access-token to see if you are missing something.

Comment: I had created a project with django where I get token like this https://github.com/Aameer/instagramGTpics/blob/master/instagramMsg/views.py#L22 . I am sure C# will have something similar which you can use to make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks Aameer for quick response. I tried creating another app in sandbox mode and it is working fine with the same line of code. But still getting same error in my live app.

Comment: Then you should check if there is some issue with setting up your production environment

Comment: The production environment was setup 2 years ago and since then it is live and working fine. I am getting this issue since last 2 days. So that is why i am not able to figure out what happened suddenly. Can you guess what it could be?

Comment: trackback any recent changes which might have caused this issue e.g updates for underlying libraries which you are using if any, recent code pushes if any. Try to figure out what changed in last two days if it was working before and once you have a list try to revert them and add them one by one to see what exactly is breaking it now.

Comment: Thanks you Aameer for your support today. I created one sample code and tested my app in live mode as well as new app created today in sandbox mode. The newly created app (sandbox) is working fine but when i tried the same code with Live app, it didn't. So i don't think the code is an issue. But do you have any idea if there are any updates published by Instagram in last few days. I checked but i couldn't see any instagram update in last few months. So issue is till there !!